# How to install allure on ubuntu 20?

Tags: python, selenium, allure

sudo apt-get install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
bridge-utils gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 libglu1-mesa libllvm11 libxatracker2 libxvmc1 linux-image-5.8.0-63-generic
linux-modules-5.8.0-63-generic linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-63-generic ubuntu-fan x11-apps x11-session-utils xbitmaps xfonts-scalable xinit xinput xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all
xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-qxl
xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.

Comment: I have used the above command to install allure but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install -y allure
```

Seems like you are using `apt-get install` but you do not specify what do you want to install, in this case you want to install allure, so you must specify.

Comment: @SreeNikitha Could you please share what you receive after using that?